# C++ disable exceptions below stack frame

Tags: c++

Is there a way to cause an exception to not propagate above a certain stack frame, while not losing stack information?

IE,

```
int foo() {
   throw 3;
}

int bar() {
   // do something here
   foo();
}

int main() {
   try {
      bar();
   } catch(...) {
      std::cout << "Caught";
   }
}
```

I want this to terminate at the 'throw 3' call, without being able to be caught by main.

is this possible?

Comment: The exception mechanism will keep searching higher scopes for an exception handler(catch).  I don't know of a way to stop that without putting an exception handler where you want it to stop.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `throw()` after functions declaration and definition

```
#include <iostream>

void* g_pStackTrace = NULL;

int foo() throw();

int foo() throw() {
   g_pStackTrace = <stack_trace_function_call>;
   throw 3;
}

int bar() {
   // do something here
   foo();
   return 0;
}

int main() {
      bar();

      if (g_pStackTrace != NULL)
      {
           // Work with our stack
      }
}
```

this will block your throw calls

stack trace function in different os

`backtrace_symbols(3)` - linux, mac osx

`CaptureStackBackTrace(...)` - windows

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/4GSG0Q)

Comment: You can also provide your own unexpecded function implementation by using `set_unexpected()` function.

Comment: @Mykola I apologize, I didn't understand what the OP was looking for. Your solution is correct, it terminates the application when you throw from within `foo()`, which is what he wants.

Comment: @Praetorian: the program works fine without any unexpected

Comment: I tried this, and it unwinds the stack - I want to preserve this information.

Comment: @Nathaniel Flath: I have add more info to deal with this problem.